# following line take lot of time to update since it has nearly 2.5l records are present

Tags: pandas

In one dataframe  i took  group count which is more than one,need to update those index sepcific column value since its 2.5l it is failing with memory error is there any fast solution for it?

```
gl_no=primary.groupby('GL Account').filter(lambda x:len(x)>1)
primary_index=primary[primary['GL Account'].isin(gl_no['GL Account'])].index
primary.loc[primary_index]['Cost Element']='01'
primary.loc[primary_index]['GL Acc Type']='P'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and comparing for boolean mask and set new values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
primary = pd.DataFrame({
        'Cost Element':list('abcdef'),
         'GL Acc Type':list('abcdef'),
         'GL Account':list('aadbbc')
})

print (primary)
  Cost Element GL Acc Type GL Account
0            a           a          a
1            b           b          a
2            c           c          d
3            d           d          b
4            e           e          b
5            f           f          c

mask=primary.groupby('GL Account')['GL Account'].transform('size') > 1
primary.loc[mask, ['Cost Element','GL Acc Type']] = ['01', 'P']
print (primary)
  Cost Element GL Acc Type GL Account
0           01           P          a
1           01           P          a
2            c           c          d
3           01           P          b
4           01           P          b
5            f           f          c
```

Comment: it's a very good explanation I won't ever forget this going forward, thanks for details explanation.